# Would it be possible to use golang protobuf client to call C++ protobuf server?

Tags: c++, go, grpc, protobuf-c, protobuf-go

I need to use an existing C++ backed protobuf server (need to connect with unix socket) to receive protobuf requests.
And I want to use golang as the protobuf client to send request to the server.
However I found the autogenerated message definition in C++ and golang is different.
There are much more definition in C++ version of protobuf in ::google::protobuf::Message.
I use the following command to generate c++ protobuf definition based on the same proto definition:

```
protoc --proto_path=src --cpp_out=. src/sample.proto
protoc --proto_path=src --go_out=. src/sample.proto
```

But with the generated sample.pb.cc, sample.pb.h and sample.pb.go, the golang client message format is not recognized by the c++ server.

Is there a way to make this golang client c++ server protobuf communication work?
Thanks.

============================
2021.1.6 update: Add an example here:

Directory structure:

```
test
├── test.pb.cc
├── test.pb.go
├── test.pb.h
└── test.proto
```

proto file:

```proto
syntax = "proto2";

option go_package = "./;test";

package test;

message test {
    required uint64 key = 1;
}
```

protoc commands to generate the test.pb.go, test.pb.h, test.ph.cc files:

```
protoc --proto_path=test --cpp_out=test test/test.proto
protoc --proto_path=test --go_out=test test/test.proto
```

Then you can see the golang generated data structure in test.pb.go:

```
type Test struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Key *uint64 `protobuf:"varint,1,req,name=key" json:"key,omitempty"`
}
```

C++ generated data structure:

```
class test : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
  ... // I'll ignore function definition

  static const int kKeyFieldNumber = 1;
  ::google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet _unknown_fields_;
  ::google::protobuf::uint64 key_;
  mutable int _cached_size_;
  ::google::protobuf::uint32 _has_bits_[(1 + 31) / 32];
  static test* default_instance_;
}
```

These two just seems not match...
For example, the `_has_bits_` field kind of plays an important role in the c++ generated code, while there's no related logic in golang generated code.

```
// required uint64 key = 1;
inline bool test::has_key() const {
  return (_has_bits_[0] & 0x00000001u) != 0;
}
inline void test::set_has_key() {
  _has_bits_[0] |= 0x00000001u;
}
inline void test::clear_has_key() {
  _has_bits_[0] &= ~0x00000001u;
}
inline void test::clear_key() {
  key_ = GOOGLE_ULONGLONG(0);
  clear_has_key();
}
inline ::google::protobuf::uint64 test::key() const {
  return key_;
}
inline void test::set_key(::google::protobuf::uint64 value) {
  set_has_key();
  key_ = value;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles A minimal example has been updated. Thanks.

Comment: The two structures look the same to me (though I'm not familiar with go)? Please show a [mre]